# Carving out details from unstructured data through Python throwing exception--> IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, google-api

I have a csv file called "data" and in the 1st column (col. name = Address) there are two addresses:

```
1.United Kingdom, London, Burlington Gardens, 3
2.United States, Menlo Park, Sand Hill Road, 3000
```

I am trying following code to return `country`, `postal_code`, `city`, `street_and_no`. in the csv file by using google geocode API. (full API key not mentioned due to security reason)

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from tqdm import *

def addresses_from_csv(path=None, column=None):

    addresses = []

    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            addresses.append(row[column])

    return addresses

# Get addresses from CSV
addresses = addresses_from_csv(path='C:/Users/kumarso/Documents/BioquellSales/Data.csv', column=0)

# Set Google Maps API key
api_key = 'AIzaSyCm5u6gF2QCccsn'

# Initialize array for transformed addresses
transformed = []
transformed.append(['Country', 'Post code', 'City', 'Street & No'])

for query in tqdm(addresses):

    # API call, storing information as JSON
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + query + '&lang=en&key=' + api_key
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    #print(data)

    # clear all values to avoid appending values from previous iterations a second time
    number = street = country = postal_code = city = '' 

    # looping over address components in JSON
    for component in data['results'][0]['address_components']:
        if 'street_number' in component['types']:
            number = component['long_name']
        elif 'route' in component['types']:
            street = component['long_name']
        elif 'country' in component['types']:
            country = component['long_name']
        elif 'postal_code' in component['types']:
            postal_code = component['long_name']
        elif 'locality' in component['types']:
            city = component['long_name']
        elif 'postal_town' in component['types']:
            city = component['long_name']
        else:
            continue

    street_and_no = street + ' ' + number
    transformed.append([country, postal_code, city, street_and_no])

with open('transformed_addresses.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in transformed:
        writer.writerow(row)

print('done')
```

I am getting the following error:

> "File "c:/ExcelP/Practice.py", line 39, in 
>       for component in data['results'][0]['address_components']: IndexError: list index out of range"

any help will be appreciated.

addition :- Print result before looping over address

```
{'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Munich', 'short_name': 'Munich', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Upper Bavaria', 'short_name': 'Upper Bavaria', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Bavaria', 'short_name': 'BY', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Germany', 'short_name': 'DE', 'types': ['country', 'political']}], 'formatted_address': 'Munich, Germany', 'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 48.2482197, 'lng': 11.7228755}, 'southwest': {'lat': 48.0616018, 'lng': 11.360796}}, 'location': {'lat': 48.1351253, 'lng': 11.5819805}, 'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 48.2482197, 'lng': 11.7228755}, 'southwest': {'lat': 48.0616018, 'lng': 11.360796}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJ2V-Mo_l1nkcRfZixfUq4DAE', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}], 'status': 'OK'}
```

Comment: Can you add ‘data’ content to your question before it raises the error?  Thanks

Comment: sorry bro! I am not clear. Should I modify the question that's what you are saying?  if yes, then I'll add the error.

Comment: yes, print the "data" value before the "if" error gives you and add the result to your question

Comment: I have added the data value.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. Thanks to Massifox for giving hint. Following actions must be taken

1) Make sure data in CSV does not have ASCII character. Print the data in console to check if feed from csv is correct.

2) Make sure API key is active.

3) Add the path in the output csv file. For example, in my question, I put 'transformed_addresses.csv' but this should be with full path.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very well :) @Siddalmia22